# WScript.Shell кодировка в UTF-8 - VBS

Tags: кодировка, shell, utf-8, vbscript

Пишу скрипт создания ярлыка на VBS и столкнулся с проблемой кодироки

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set shortcut = sh.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\Компьютер\Desktop\test.lnk")
shortcut.TargetPath = "D://Launcher\test.exe"
shortcut.Save
```

т.к. у многих в странах СНГ компьютера и папки названы кириллицей, то возникает ошибка `Не удается сохранить ярлык C:\Users\"непонятные символы"\Desktop\test.lnk`. Как решить проблему с кодировкой в скрипте выше? Уже весь Google вдоль и поперек облазил.

Comment: Немного не понятны условия. Если необходимо создать ярлык на рабочем столе, то почему бы не [получить путь к рабочему столу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596990/) средствами VBscript?

Comment: @Daemon-5, спасибо, помогло! Добавь комментарий как ответ, закрою вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если необходимо создать ярлык на рабочем столе, то можно получить [путь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596990/) к рабочему столу средствами VBscript.

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
wscript.echo(strDesktop)
```